# Returning a Financial Year & Quarter date in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like Excel to be able to return the related Financial Year and Financial Quarter of a particular date. i.e.

**Date**
1st April 2020

**Financial Year**
20/21

**Quarter** 
Q1

Our financial year begins from 1st April (not 1st January) and the quarters fall from that date.

What equation can I use in Excel to make this work?

Please see below table denoting what a financial year looks like for us and the relative 4 quarters.

[image]

Thank you

David

Comment: Do you have an existing "lookup table" or "reference table" wherein you've got a start date and/or range of dates, and then the associated numerical value for the quarter and year out beside it somewhere already?  This varies by company, so your company's is likely different.  So you'll need to possibly consider this first.

If you have these, can you provide this reference table in an [edit] to your post?  Normally we disapprove of screenshots, but if you provide the column/row headers, this should work.

Comment: Thank you. I've uploaded the table below. My apologies as I don't know how to add it in table format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and dirty (can be simplified):

- Financial Year:

```
=IF(MONTH(B1)>=4,RIGHT(YEAR(B1),2)&"/"&RIGHT(YEAR(B1),2)+1,RIGHT(YEAR(B1)-1,2)&"/"&RIGHT(YEAR(B1),2))
```

- Quarter:

```
="Q"&IF(ROUNDUP(MONTH(B1)/3,0)-1=0,4,ROUNDUP(MONTH(B1)/3,0)-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Good use of `CHOOSE`... was going that way but as I mentioned, "quick and dirty."

Comment: Ha... thanks. I'd suggest @JustynaMK's CHOOSE as that is a bit cleaner for the quarters.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using for Financial Year:

`=IF(MONTH(B1)>3,YEAR(B1)&"/"&YEAR(B1)+1,YEAR(B1)-1&"/"&YEAR(B1))`

& for the quarter:

`="Q"&CHOOSE(ROUNDUP(MONTH(B1)/3,0),4,1,2,3)`

[image]